# Requirement is to add 4 line if the matching pattern followed by the next pattern is unmatched along with count number in power shell

Tags: powershell, text, count

Hello my input file will be like below,my requiremnet is to add 4 line if the macthing pattern folled by the next pattern is unmacthed along with  count number.

i will check look for the socket and if matches will incrremnt the line count to +1 toi get the next line and look for the word "address",if the address is not present i need to insert a set of line "communication.manageraddress_9,communication.manageraddress_10,communication.manageraddress_11" netx to the line.

communication.manageraddress_7=xxx.com 
communication.managerid_7=xxx 
communication.managerport_7=xxx 
communication.socket_7=xx

communication.manageraddress_8=xxx.com 
communication.managerid_8=xxx 
communication.managerport_8=xxx 
communication.socket_8=plain

Added by Manager

communication.managerhealthmon_4=true 
communication.protocolrev_4=3 
communication.managerhealthmon_1=true 
communication.protocolrev_1=2

output will be like this

communication.manageraddress_7=xxx.com 
communication.managerid_7=xxx 
communication.managerport_7=xxx 
communication.socket_7=xx

communication.manageraddress_8=xxx.com 
communication.managerid_8=xxx 
communication.managerport_8=xxx 
communication.socket_8=plain

communication.manageraddress_9=xxx.com 
communication.managerid_9=xxx 
communication.managerport_9=xxx 
communication.socket_9=plain

communication.manageraddress_10=xxx.com 
communication.managerid_10=xxx 
communication.managerport_1o=xxx 
communication.socket_1o=plain

Added by Manager

communication.managerhealthmon_4=true 
communication.protocolrev_4=3 
communication.managerhealthmon_1=true 
communication.protocolrev_1=2

this my script and i am struck with insert into text file along with increment number,can some one help in power shell.

```
        $files = $File = 'C:\Users\rseerala\Desktop\ARUN\in.txt'
        #$NewContent = Get-Content -Path $File 
        foreach($file in $files){
                    $content = Get-Content $file
                    for($i = 0; $i -lt $content.Count; $i++){
                       $line = $content[$i]
                       if ($line.Contains("socket"))
                                  {
                                   $line = $content[$i+2]
                                            if ($line.Contains("address"))
                                            {
                                            Write-Host "This line starts with 6"
                                            }}}}
```

Comment: Honestly.. I have no idea what you're trying to do here. Repeat blocks of (4 lines) text and increment the number before the `=` sign as soon as you find the word `socket`?

Comment: Yes Theo..correct..

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so if I understand correctly, this is what you want:

```
#read the file as a single multiline string
$txt = Get-Content -Path 'C:\Users\rseerala\Desktop\ARUN\in.txt' -Raw

# if it contains the magic word '.socket_' followed by a number
if ($txt -match '\.socket_\d+') {
    # first split off the 'Added by Manager' stuff
    $content, $managerAdded = ($txt -split 'Added by Manager').Trim()
    # split the content part into separate blocks of 4 lines
    $blocks = $content -split '(\r?\n){2}' | Where-Object { $_ -match '\S' }
    # get the index value from the last block
    $index = [int]([regex] '(?i)\.socket_(\d+)').Match($blocks[-1]).Groups[1].Value

    # now repeat the blocks you already have and output copies with incremented indices
    $newBlocks = ($blocks | ForEach-Object {
        $_ -replace '_\d+=', ('_{0}=' -f ++$index)
    }) -join "`r`n`r`n"

    # finally, combine the content part with the new blocks 
    # and the 'Added by Manager' lines with double newlines
    $result = $content, $newBlocks, 'Added by Manager', $managerAdded -join "`r`n`r`n"

    # output on screen
    $result

    # write to a new file
    $result | Set-Content -Path 'C:\Users\rseerala\Desktop\ARUN\out.txt'
}
else {
    Write-Warning "The file does not contain the word '.socket_' followed by a number.."
}
```

Output:

```
communication.manageraddress_7=xxx.com
communication.managerid_7=xxx
communication.managerport_7=xxx
communication.socket_7=xx

communication.manageraddress_8=xxx.com
communication.managerid_8=xxx
communication.managerport_8=xxx
communication.socket_8=plain

communication.manageraddress_9=xxx.com
communication.managerid_9=xxx
communication.managerport_9=xxx
communication.socket_9=plain

communication.manageraddress_10=xxx.com
communication.managerid_10=xxx
communication.managerport_10=xxx
communication.socket_10=plain

Added by Manager

communication.managerhealthmon_4=true
communication.protocolrev_4=3
communication.managerhealthmon_1=true
communication.protocolrev_1=2
```